# Are the edge states of a topological insulator only zero energy states?

Tags: topological-insulators

For non-trivial [topological insulators](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological_insulator), are the edge states only zero energy states? Or are boundary states of different energies also available?

Comment: Generally speaking zero-energy states exist on defects (i.e. domain walls, vortices, monopoles, ...). A very general classification has been worked out http://arxiv.org/abs/1006.0690.

Answer (score 1):

In principle there is no reason they should be only at zero energy. The following picture is from the review of Hasan and Kane: As you can see, the black curve denotes the edge spectrum, which exists across the band gap of the bulk. [image]